# How can I find P(X=1) mathematically?

Tags: probability, random-variables

See [this video at 5:42](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BswLMKgXzU).

[image]

I know $P(X=1) = 0$.

How can I find $P(X=1)$ mathematically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
P(X=1) = F(1) - lim_{y\rightarrow1^-} F(y)
$$
and $F$ is continuous in a neighbourhood of $1$, then we obtain
$$
P(X=1) = F(1) - F(1) = 0 .
$$

Note: $lim_{y\rightarrow1^-} F(y)$ means the limit of $F(y)$ when $y$ is approaching $1$ from below.

By the way, looking at the image, since $F(y) = P(X \leq y)$, we have that $P(X \geq 1.8) = 1 - F(1.8) + P(X = 1.8)$. $F(1.8)$ can be computed by the formula and $P(X = 1.8) = 0$, due to the continuity of $F$ in a neighbourhood of $1.8$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $x$ within a continuous distribution $X$,
$$P(X=x)=0$$
as probability can be thought of as the area represented by this region and the region represented by a single line has no area.

Answer (score 0):

The CDF is continuous, so there are no point masses (no jumps in the CDF). This means $P(X=x)=0$ for all $x$.

That's because for any given $x$, $P(x-h<X\leq x+h)=F(x+h)-F(x-h)$. Let $h\to 0$ to get $P(X=x)=0$ by continuity of $F$.